# Dimmer switch on 3-way circuit only working 90% of the time, is it a bad switch or something else?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture, dimmer-switch

I installed a dimmer switch on a 3-way circuit that was working correctly.  The other switch is a standard on-off switch.  The fixtures they control are halogen light fixtures.

About 10% of the time, when I try to turn on the dimmer switch (at full power), nothing happens.

Is there anything special about setting up a dimmer switch in this configuration, or do I simply have a bad switch?

---

***UPDATE***

Dimmer switch is a FEIT Electric (UL E478968), Model 72200.

Comment: Did you install a 3-way dimmer?  When it doesn’t work what is the solution, change the position of the other switch? Or turn it off and back on from the dimmer?

Comment: @Tyson Great questions.  I did install a 3-way dimmer.  The instructions say it can be used either as a 2-way or 3-way dimmer.  When it doesn't work, I flip the dimmer switch on and off a few times, and then it works.  I haven't tried changing the position of the other switch.

Comment: What make and model is said dimmer?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I just updated the question with that information.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the installation instructions? Google's batting 0 on them, and Feit's own site doesn't provide a clear path to them either...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Do you know how to do that on StackExchange?  Maybe just add it as an image?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard -- yeah, if you have the installation instructions in paper form, posting a clear picture/scan as an image works best

Comment: I’m gonna say it’s a bad dimmer.  Feit makes cheap crap.